# Definition of fractional Laplacian on a compact manifold?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, manifolds, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus

How does one define the fractional Laplacian operator $(-\Delta)^s$ on a compact Riemannian manifold?

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is defined
$$ (-\Delta)^s f(x) = c_{n,s} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{f(x) - f(y)} {|x-y|^{n+2s}} \mathrm d y $$
where $c_{n,s}$ is a constant. Can we simply replace the integral to be an intergral over the manifold $M$ and change the denominator to $g(x,y)^{n+2s}$ where $g$ is the distance function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that formula won't work. But you can use a spectral definition. There is an orthonormal basis $\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ for $L^2(M)$ consisting of eigenfunctions of $-\Delta$, with corresponding eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}$.  Then for $u = \sum_i u_i \phi_i$, put
$$(-\Delta)^s u(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (\lambda_i)^s u_i \phi_i(x).$$

Comment: Thanks. There's no way to write it like an integral as I tried to in my OP?

Comment: For each $s$, there is a function $G_s:M\times M\to \mathbb R$, called the _Green kernel_ for $(-\Delta)^s$, such that $(-\Delta)^s f(x) = \int_M G_s(x,y)f(y)dV(y)$. But in general, you can't write $G_s$ explicitly in terms of the metric.

Comment: Thank you. If $M$ were a compact hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then do we get anything?

Comment: What terms/resources should I search for if I want to learn more about this "spectral definition"? Most functional analysis materials simply talk about finding the point/residual/continuous spectrum, but I can't find much about this decomposition with respect to an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions. Specifically, what kind of "functions" can I take of $-\Delta_g$ on a manifold? Can I shove $-\Delta_g$ into most any function?

Comment: @Patch: A good place to start is [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_functional_calculus).

Comment: @maximumtag You could check this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0001870818300318 There you can find an explicit integral representation like in the one in Euclidean space but with an error term. Hope this helps you.